# Ninject: Pass private member as constructor argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using Ninject with ASP.NET MVC. Basically, I want to pass the protected member _connectionStringBuilder in the BaseController class as a constructor argument to the class SourceCodeManager.

I basically do some processing at the controller level and then I want to pass that to the my various Business layer classes like SourceCodeManager.

I know this sounds a bit funky, but I basically want to pass the same variable _connectionStringBuilder to all of my Business Layer classes.
(I am trying to upgrade a classic ASP application where they store the username and password in cookies!)

```
 public class SourceCodeManager :  ParisDataAccessManager, ISourceCodeManager
    {
        SourceCodeManager(IParisConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder)
            : base(connectionStringBuilder)
        {

        }

        public List<SourceCodeList> GetManualSourceCodes()
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringManager.GetConnectionString()))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var manualSourcesCodes = connection
                    .Query<SourceCodeList>("select source_cd, source_desc where feeder_system_cd = 'ME'")
                    .ToList();
                return manualSourcesCodes;
            }
        }
    }

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [Inject]
    public IParisConnectionStringBuilder _connectionStringBuilder { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% I understand what your question is.

However, if you only want a single instance of IParisConnectionStringBuilder in your whole application, look at registering as a singleton in NInject.

Syntax is something like:

```
Bind<IParisConnectionStringBuilder>().To<ParisConnectionStringBuilder>().InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! I inject a concrete implementation of IParisConnectionStringBuilder in the BaseController class using the InSingletonScope() and that same instance gets passed to the constructor of all my business layer classes.